# No Java virtual machine found starting Eclipse 3.6.1 on Windows 7 64bit machine

Tags: eclipse, windows-7, java

I know some C# and I use Visual Studio 2008 but now I am trying to help my son with some basic Java programs. I have installed what I think is the proper version of Eclipse:

eclipse-SDK-3.6.1-win32-x86_64

I have a little "hello world" starter .java file I want to run and play with but I cannot even get started on this machine. I get this message immediately:

"A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: 
C:\Users\john\Documents\eclipse-SDK-3.6.1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe
javaw.exe in your current PATH"

This is an AMD Quad-Core Processor and I'm running 64bit Windows 7 so I believe the Eclipse SDK is also properly 64bit. I have been having a heck of a time trying to locate the proper Java "virtual machine" / JRE / JDK or whatever and get it downloaded such that this problem goes away and I get Eclipse running.

I am a total rookie on Java and its terminology and environs and would really appreciate some basic advice on this. Thanks.

Comment: "I know some C# and I use Visual Studio 2008..." Eclipse is analogous to VS2008; the JRE/JDK is (roughly) analogous to the .NET CLR.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hop over to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and download the Java SDK. I think this will get you going unless I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: Thanks. There was still a lot of strange stuff to wade through but I must have picked the right thing because now Eclipse came up OK. I downloaded from: https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewFilteredProducts-SingleVariationTypeFilter

Comment: oops - bad URL. Here is what I chose for my PC:               Download Java SE Runtime Environment 6u23 for Windows x64, Multi-language

Answer (score 4):

Just go through this steps, well explained in step by step :-)

[Setting Up Eclipse with Java](http://www.ugrad.cs.ubc.ca/~cs211/tutorials/Eclipse/Eclipse_Java_Windows_XP.html)

Answer (score 2):

Download the JDK from here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

The Eclipse SDK only contains the Eclipse IDE AFAIK :p

Answer (score 0):

For pure Eclipse you do not need a JDK, just a JRE, so the easiest way is to go to http://java.com and allow it to install Java on your computer.

Then Eclipse will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running 64 bit Windows and Eclipse, make sure you install 64 bit java!

See this question: [Failed to load the JNI shared Library (JDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk)