# How do I get Eclipse (32 bit) to run properly in Windows 7? Non-administrator

Tags: eclipse, windows-7

I've just downloaded the JDK ( http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u27-b07/jdk-6u27-windows-i586.exe ), 32 bit.  And eclipse ( http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7.1-201109091335/eclipse-SDK-3.7.1-win32.zip ), 32 bit.  And Windows 7 is 32 bit.  None of the "you need the 64 bit JVM" solutions will work here.

When I run eclipse.exe, all I get is a dialog box:

```
Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll".
```

That file does exist.  If I run Eclipse as an administrator it works.  I categorically do not want to do that.  I want my user account to own the files I will be creating and editing.

If I add

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe
```

to eclipse.ini it will run, but then I cannot pin it to the task bar.

How do I get Eclipse to
A) Run
B) As my user account
C) Pinned to the task bar?

Answer (score 0):

You should try, as illustrated in [this `eclipse.ini`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659) to reference a JRE within a JDK, not a JRE directly:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_27/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
```

Comment: That gives the same error, except with that path.  However "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin\javaw.exe" runs, but behaves identically.

Comment: @arantius: did you try with the same `eclipse.ini` than the one I mention?  You can also try and copy the jdk directory elsewhere, in case there is some limitations due to the fact it is in "`Progam Files`"

Comment: Install to C:\Java and launching (stock) Eclipse gives the same error (Now "Failed to load the JNI shared library C:\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll.").  Edit just the vm line, same almost working behavior.  Any vm pointing to jvm.dll fails to load, same error.  Any, including that ini verbatim, pointing to javaw.exe gives the no-pinning behavior.

Comment: @arantius: then maybe this can help: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_mainclass.xml (taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk)

Comment: @arantius that thread points out to 64-bit JDK (http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/170758/) which shouldn't be your issue. But it still would be interesting to check a 64-bit JDK with a 64-bits eclipse.

Comment: That says "During Java installation process".  Java installs fine.  Eclipse doesn't run.  I have a 32 bit OS so ... 64 bit anything is not a solution.

Comment: @arantius: right... sorry for the false leads. At least I tried.