# Eclipse error: Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll

Tags: java, android, eclipse, java-native-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Failed to Load the JNI shared Library (JDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk)

I have download new classic eclipse 64 bits
i also changed in eclipse.ini and android jdk tools also install 
but still getting below error.
Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll 
how to solve problem?

Please Help me.

Comment: Have you checked if the file exists?

Answer (score 7):

From this what i am seeing is you are using 32 bit version of java.

**To overcome this issue you must install 64-bit version of Java.**

Comment: I had the same problem and it was because 32-bit version is installed instead of 64-bit, thanks

Answer (score -2):

Try to set your computer's path (in environmental variables) to the bin file of your Java JDK ( C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin).

Comment: Why? It's already looking there. Not an answer.