# eclips dont find java in win7 on vmware for android programin

Tags: java, android, sdk, vmware

I have installed the JDK and then I installed the Android SDK and its package for Android 7 and 10. I can create a virtual machine for Android and see it, but when I try to run eclipse, a error message box opens and says `"Can't find javaw.exe in this location"` (the directory where eclipse is located), and I am unable to run Eclipse.

Any help resolving this issue would be much appreciated

Comment: This might help you out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk

Answer (score 1):

You should install java runtime environment seperately.. Or if that also doesn't solve ur problem final working solution would be add environment variable of JDK or JRE on ur windows7.

Hope this would solve your problem.
Cheers!

Comment: you mean that i install jdk again?

Comment: Don't forget to Hit "Solved" if your problem get solved, so this question is removed from **Unanswered** category, so other stackoverflow mates could spend their precious time in answering other questions. Thankyou.

Comment: You have installed jdk right? Just install jre seperately[because once this thing solved my problem] else adding an environment variable in windows7 by giving path to ur current javaw.exe would definitely solve ur problem

Comment: I use eclips in my base win and its run easyly but in vmware after install sdk ,its dont run

Comment: Ok, but try it by adding an environment variable of javaw in ur vmware. It would work.

Comment: Open up Windows' System Properties from the control panel and hunt down the environment variables section:

Add a JAVA_HOME entry pointing to the directory where the JDK is installed (e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jre6)
Find the Path entry and add the following onto the end ;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
OK the changes
Restart eclipse so that it is aware of the new environment
Most Java tools will now be able to find your Java installation either by using the JAVA_HOME environment variable or by looking for java.exe / javaw.exe in the Path environment variable.

Comment: If you dont understand the above. Try following this [link](http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2010/11/29/set-environment-variables-in-windows-7-for-java/)

Comment: ok tnx,i do it and test java in cmd and its successed but now error is:faild load jvm.dll