# How to setup android development on windows 7 pro

Tags: android

Interested in Android but new in development. I am using windows 7 PRO for android app development.  I did the following and I encountered this error msg : failed to load the JNI shared library

I took the following steps:

1. Create a folder with name : AndroidSDK  in c:\ Program files (x86)
2. - Downloaded the Android SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
     and run the Android Installer
   - use the suggested folder name Android SDK  and place it in AndroidSDK in Program files  (x86)
3. run the SDK Manager and installed all required packages
4. Download Eclipse Classic 4.2.1 from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/.

   - after extracting the file, Copy and paste the Eclipse Folder in  AndroidSDK ( this folder in C:\Program files (x86))
5. Have tried both JDK 6 and JDK 7  from  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7u7-downloads-1836413.html

   - Install it under Enclipse Folder:
     When double click on the Eclipse application ico, I got this error msg
     failed to load the JNI shared library

Can you help me how to setup Andriod development on windows 7 pro?

Thanks

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your JDK is 64 and that your Eclipse is 64-bit.

[Failed to load the JNI shared Library (JDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk)

Comment: 1) Since I install Android SDK in C:'Program files (x86), So I must use JDK 32-bits and Ecipse 32bit ?  2) Can I install Android SDK in C;\program files (64bits) so I will use JDK and Ecipse 64 bits? Thanks

Comment: #1 / #2: it doesn't matter where you install them; if your system is 64-bit, then you need to install the JDK 64-bit and the Eclipse 64-bit.

Comment: I am having problems. Do I need IE9 64bits on Win7 pro to download JDK 64bits as well as Eclipse 64 bits?  After installling ie9 64 bits but the java website say mine is 32-bits browsers. Any suggestion to download?

Comment: would appreciate if you provide me the link for JDK 64 bits. Thanks

Comment: Got it working now. It is very misleading from the java.com which specify 64bits browser requirement.