# Error launching Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-native-interface

I am getting the following error when I open Eclipse (Juno)

```
Failed to load the JNI shared library “C:\Program Files
(x86)\Java\jdkl.6.0_11\jre\bin\client\jvmdll”.
```

The spash screen appears and the above error message appears in a dialog and nothing else.

I also have Eclipse Ganymede installed which opens without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have some wrong combination of 64 vs. 32 bit between os, java and eclipse, like here: [Failed to load the JNI shared Library (JDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk)

Comment: My OS is 64 bit. How do I find out whether java and eclipse are 32 bit or 64 bit. By the way, in the beginning (a few months back) I was able to open eclipse and there was no such problem. Somehow, all of the environment path variables got deleted. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @rsrgf Probably you should check your environment, probably a 32 bit jdk/jre is set. To verify if java is running on 64 bit you can run: `java -version` and check the output, it should print something like: `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit`. For Eclipse you can easily download a 64 binary from: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/