# I am trying to run eclipse (java installed). The application can find my javaw.exe but cannot execute it. Here's my .ini file and the error prompt:

Tags: android, eclipse

Here's my eclipse.ini which I got from the bundle:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

// I add this in
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe

--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v21.0.1-543035
```

And the error prompt when I try executing the file:

```
Java was started but returned exit code=13
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v21.0.1-543035
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar C:\Program Files
(x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\eclipe\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_
1.3.0v21020522-1813.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher C:\Program Files (x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library C:\Program Files
(x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equniox.launcher.
win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813\eclipse_1503.dll
-startup C:\Program Files
(x86)\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equniox.launcher_
1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 1dd0_5c
-product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
-vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v21.0.1-543035
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar C:\Program Files
(x86)\at-bundle-windows-x86_64\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_
1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

Can anyone kindly help me to find my error? 
Is it a directory problem, or do I require another OS to run eclipse?
Btw, I got this line

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
```

from [Failed to load the JNI shared Library (JDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk).

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461607/cant-start-eclipse-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-13.

Comment: The paths might be invalid, since it contains backslash and space. I'm not sure if it's a good idea to add C:\Program Files
(x86)\at-bundle-windows-x86_64\eclipse\\

Answer (score -1):

i always copy the jre folder into the same directory where my eclipse.exe is located. so i can make sure my eclipse runs independently from the installed java version. within the preferences you can define a seperate jdk/jre (menu: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs) which will be used to run your code.

btw: good practice is also to use a wordspace per project to stay organized. you can export and import your workspace settings (menu: File -> Import/Export -> Gneral -> Preferences)

this link could also help -> http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the help. Instead of using the jre folder, I went to download the 64-bit java jdk and redirected the directory to the javaw.exe in that folder ie. 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin\javaw.exe
and it works now :D