# Birt report viewer doesn't start

Tags: java, java-native-interface, java-7, birt

After installing java JDK1.7.0_15 on my computer, my Birt report viewer designer 3.7.2 doesn't start. This error message is printed instead:

> Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_15..\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll".

I tried downloading and installing the new version of Birt v4.7.2 but i'm still getting the same error.

My os is Windows 7 on 64 bit.
I use eclipse indigo and juno for my project and all goes well..

Can anyone help me?

Re-Edit:
I don't know why but if i remove in PATH system variable this statement:
`;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15`

and i move jre directory in the eclipse and birt home directory all return on the normality.

Comment: i don't think is a duplicated because eclipse don't have any problem. I have OS and JAVA and ECLIPSE on 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I think that this is the same problem as [Failed to load the JNI shared Library (JDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk) except that it is happening when you start the Birt Viewer not Eclipse itself.

In short you need:

- a 64 bit OS, a 64 bit Java installation and a 64 bit Birt report viewer, OR
- a 32 or 64 bit OS, a 32 bit Java installation and a 32 bit Birt report viewer.

And you need to make sure that the launcher for the Birt report viewer uses the right Java installation ... if you have multiple Java installations on your machine.

Comment: I suppose you are rigth but the only problem is i can't find another version of Birt report designer install.

Comment: What about the AllInOne bundle?  http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-and-report-developers/junosr1  There are download links for 32 and 64 bit Windows.

Comment: Because my eclipse without any plugin is slow and i don't want to overloaded it. But if i have problem for another week i try it..thanks for the propose..