# Android tools not working on IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I recently moved from eclipse to Intellij and I have problem with using Android tools. When I click Tools->Android->Monitor(DDMS included) I get error saying:

Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin..\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll".

I am using lastest community edition of Intellij. I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Can you confirm that path is valid? Is everything setup on your IDE, SDK, etc?

Comment: Yep, everything is working I can deploy apps ,run them on device ,emulator or debug

Comment: Does it work if you start it from `%ANDROID_SDK%\tools\monitor.bat`?

Comment: Yes, it works when I start it this way

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk they say that cause is diffrent architecture of IDE and SDK ,may it be the cause for IntelliJ too?

Comment: Actually IDEA starts this file: `%ANDROID_SDK%\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64\monitor.exe` if you are using 64-bit OS. Does it work for you outside of IDEA?

Comment: You can replace `IDEA\bin\log.xml` with [this version](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2752840/ShareXmod/2013-03/log.xml), then restart IDEA, start monitor, when it fails look inside [idea.log](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446) for the command line being executed, then try to run it outside of IDEA.

Comment: Here is log file from last lunching of IDE and trying to run Monitor, I can't track anything from this log http://speedy.sh/sY9ES/idea.log

Comment: This log doesn't contain relevant info, I'll check later why. Did you try running monitor.exe, does it work?

Comment: You mean android.bat from Android_SDK->tools? Yes, it works correctly

Comment: No, I mean `%ANDROID_SDK%\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64\monitor.exe`, see my comments above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is simple! Just use `[IntelliJ Idea Directory]\bin\idea64.exe`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. My environment and my solution:

- I have a 64bit Java. You can know your version with this code snippet:

  ```
  public class Test {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
         System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model") );
     }  
  }
  ```
- I was running the 32bit version of Intellij ("C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.1.3\bin\idea.exe")
- I just change to idea64.exe ("C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12.1.3\bin\idea64.exe"). Make a direct access to your desktop.
- It worked ... like a boss.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need a 64-bit Package:

```
64-bit Windows OS
64-bit Java (JDK it must be 1.7 )
```

Please try with this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my environment, the cause was that Intellij Community started as a 32bit executable, while the Android Monitor tool is a 64bit exe.
So, a clean solution is to start Intellij with a 64bit JVM:

1. define the environment variable IDEA_JDK pointing to the path of the 64bit JDK (for example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43)
2. modify the shortcut used to run Intellij in order to launch `idea.bat` (instead of `idea.exe`)

When idea.bat finds the environment variable `%IDEA_JDK%`, it runs Intellij using the 64bit JVM.

This solved the problem (in my environment).

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my JAVA_HOME environment variable to point at the 64-bit Java.