# Java failed to load JNI shared library

Tags: java, windows-8, eclipse-juno

When trying to run eclipse on a new windows 8 installation I get this error after updating the path variable.

[image]

What can be done? Can you help me resolve the error? I have everything 64-bit. I changed eclipse.ini to point to the 64-bute javaw and then I get another error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mismatch between your bit versions of java and OS

These are the working sets

```
32-bit OS - 32-bit JDK - 32-bit Eclipse (32-bit only)
64-bit OS - 32-bit JDK - 32-bit Eclipse
64-bit OS - 64-bit JDK - 64bit Eclipse (64-bit only)
```

[Refer this on OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk) and Follow http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp