# Failed to Load JNI shared library when trying to use titanium

Tags: titanium

I am having difficulty with Titanium cross mobile development platform, i am getting error `"failed to load JNI shared library c:\programfiles\java\jdk 1.6.0 _45\bin\server\jvm.dll.`

could any one help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you read [System Requirements](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Quick_Start-section-29004949_QuickStart-SystemRequirements)?

From Documentation:

> For Windows, the 32-bit version of Java JDK is required regardless of
> whether Titanium is running on a 32-bit or 64-bit system.

Try to install additional 32bit version of Java (without removing the 64bit) and set the system variable.

You can refer the following links for it

1. [Failed to load the jni shared library jvmdll Titanium](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/150963/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jvmdll)
2. [Failed to load the jni shared library jdk - Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk)

Hope it helped you

Comment: Hi Anand Thanks for your responce

Comment: Hi Anand,i install java 32 bit version  in a different location and it works,thanks for your great help.

Comment: Hi Anand In my titanium studio,i started with app.js file i am trying to create new window there but i am getting error,Is this a right way to develop in titanium.

Comment: var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

Comment: @Akshay: It will work only if there exists a window. Otherwise you need to create window using createWindow method. Please read the documentation from http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api