# Falied to load the JNI shared library

Tags: java, eclipse, titanium

I have installed Titanium Studio and now I'm getting the error shown in the image when I try to run it. And nothing happens when clicked OK. I searched on the web and re-installed JRE 64bit, set jre/bin and jdk/bin in PATH environment variables, but didn't fix the issue. What am I supposed to do to solve this?[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037022/failed-to-load-jni-shared-library-when-trying-to-use-titanium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read [System Requirements](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Quick_Start-section-29004949_QuickStart-SystemRequirements)?

From Documentation:

> For Windows, the 32-bit version of Java JDK is required regardless of
> whether Titanium is running on a 32-bit or 64-bit system.

Try to install additional 32bit version of Java (without removing the 64bit) and set the system variable.

Hope it helped you

Answer (score 1):

If you use a 64-bit JRE, all your environment must be 64-bit:

- 64-bit OS
- 64-bit Java (JRE + JDK)
- <del>64-bit IDE (Titanium)</del> => As pointed out by @Anand, [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Quick_Start-section-29004949_QuickStart-SystemRequirements) says:

> For Windows, **the 32-bit version of Java JDK is required** regardless of
>   whether Titanium is running on a 32-bit or 64-bit system.

Make sure all is fine, then check if `jvm.dll` exists at the specified location. If not, change it in `eclipse.ini`, by adding:

```
-vm
C:\path\to\your\jvm.dll
```