# Android Build Error: Unable to locate Java VM. Please set JAVA_HOME environment variable

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I'm using Ti Studio on Win7, and my project builds and works when I have my Android plugged in via USB and I run using "Android Device".

However, when I try to buid it for distribution I get:

```
[ERROR] Program launch failed. Unable to locate Java VM. Please set JAVA_HOME environment variable.
```

I have looked at [this thread](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/146294/program-launch-failed-unable-to-locate-java-vm-please-set-javahome-environment-variable) which describes a similar problem, and verified that JAVA_HOME is set:

```
+&gt;echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29
```

Also, in Ti Studio I have verified that Preferences->Studio->Platforms->Android has the "Android SDK Home" set to the path where Android SDK is installed.

Can anyone guide me on what else I need to do to fix this?

Thanks!

#### UPDATE FOR ANAND

```
+>javac -version
javac 1.6.0_29

+>java -version
java version "1.7.0_01"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_01-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Make sure you have set all environment variables. To check this open your command prompt type following commands `java`, `javac`, `adb` if any of this has failed, you need to set the variable properly

Comment: Hi Andand, all three of those commands work fine.  Other ideas?

Comment: Which version of OS you have 32 or 64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read [System Requirements](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Quick_Start-section-29004949_QuickStart-SystemRequirements)?

From Documentation:

> For Windows, the 32-bit version of Java JDK is required regardless of
>   whether Titanium is running on a 32-bit or 64-bit system.

Try to install additional 32bit version of Java (without removing the 64bit) and set the system variable.

You may refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037022/failed-to-load-jni-shared-library-when-trying-to-use-titanium/17037236#17037236).

Hope it helped you

Comment: Anand, I have upated my OP with info about the java versions I see from the command line.  I am a little confused though: I have multiple versions of java installed on my machine -- do I need to change which version are executed by default system wide (ie, by changing my PATH) or is it a configuration within TiStudio I need to make?

Comment: You have to change the path of java to 32 bit version. Because titanium works with 32 bit java only. I have updated my answer. I did a mistake in the links

Comment: Ok I tried this, but it did not help.  I now have `>which java` returning `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.EXE` but I get the same error as in the original OP during the android build to distribute process.

Answer (score 1):

Configure environment variables as mentioned  [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/mobile/mobile-build-windows) and JDK must be 32 bit