# Error missing java sdk. please make sure java sdk is on your path

Tags: titanium

I'm starting with the Titanium tool, but I can not build for mobile. This error appears:

> Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.1.2, Titanium SDK version 3.1.3.GA
>   Copyright (c) 2012-2013 Appcelerator, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
>   **[ERROR]: "Missing Java SDK Please make sure Java SDK is on your PATH.**

I've tried to put the environment variables

```
"C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_03;JAVA_HOME%/bin%"
"C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45;JAVA_HOME%/bin%"

"C: \ Java \ jdk1.6.0_03 \ bin"
"C: \ Java \ jdk1.7.0_45 \ bin"

"C: \ Java \ jdk1.6.0_03"
"C: \ Java \ jdk1.7.0_45"
```

I tried the all 6 and restarting the computer. What is missing?

Comment: They should be in the PATH variable, also, are you sure that the Java SDK is on these locations?, by the way, the correct form should be first two ones.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942350/android-build-error-unable-to-locate-java-vm-please-set-java-home-environment/19945604#19945604

Answer (score 0):

[path settings](http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/mobile/mobile-build-windows)

- The 32-bit version of the JDK is required regardless of whether
  Titanium is running on a 32-bit or 64-bit Windows system.