# Titanium SDK error

Tags: java, android, titanium, appcelerator

I have **java 1.6** installed on my **windows 8**,i have configured the path and environment variables. And they work perfectly well coz i have eclipse installed on my system too. But titanium doesnt launch my project. I get the following error on build. Please i really need help with this.

> [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination.
>        Process exit value was 1 Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.1.2,
>        Titanium SDK version 3.1.3.GA Copyright (c) 2012-2013, Appcelerator, Inc.
>        All Rights Reserved. [ERROR] : "Missing Java SDK. Please make sure Java SDK is on your PATH

Comment: did you check that it really is on the PATH variable? when you start Titanium and check the statues of android is it active?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037022/failed-to-load-jni-shared-library-when-trying-to-use-titanium/17037236#17037236)? If you're having a 64 bit system install 32 bit java and set environment variable according to the new path. Since Titanium works only with 32 bit java version

Comment: Hi Thanks,i went back to the old version of titanium.