# Android SDK Eclipse Error (Fail to Load Library)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-sdk-2.3

I am having trouble installing the Android SDK, specifically with Eclipse. Every time i try to open it, I get this error message:

[image: Error]

That file exists in that path, and i have no idea why it cant be opened.

[image: jvm.dll]

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working pairings of OS, JDK and Eclipse Android SDK:

```
32-bit OS - 32-bit JDK - 32-bit Eclipse -32 bit android sdk (32-bit only)
64-bit OS - 32-bit JDK - 32-bit Eclipse -32 bit android sdk
64-bit OS - 64-bit JDK - 64bit Eclipse - 64 bit android sdk(64-bit only)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you're version of Eclipse and JDK match, either both 64-bit or both 32-bit.

Second, the -vm argument in `eclipse.ini` should point to the java executable. See 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini for examples.