# On starting eclipse, it gives an error "Java was started but returned exit code=13"

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7

I am trying to start eclipse after installing java 7 and adding the line

```
-vm
C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
```

to the eclipse.ini file. Still i am getting the error "Java was started but returned exit code=13".
[image]

I just want to know how to start eclipse. Even if i have to install eclipse, java, jre all over again.
Any suggestion will do!

My eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Progra~2\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

On pasting the jre in eclipse folder i am getting this error:

[image]

Comment: If nothing works out, copy the jre directory to eclipse directory and remove the vm argument and start the eclipse.

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan : can you please elaborate on what exactly should be the path that i should copy?

Comment: remove -vm argument completely (including the path to javaw.exe). Copy the jre folder which is present inside (jdk1.7.0_45) to eclipse folder where eclipse.exe is available

Comment: on copying the jre folder i am getting error: "failed to load jni shared library"

Comment: Refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is to put the new jdk path in eclipse.ini

> -vm 
>  
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin\javaw.exe 
>  
>   or the your new jdk path.
>   
>   make sure that you type the above just before the -vmargs and after the OpenFile

that solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have installed the correct java that your OS requires. Meaning, if you are running a 64 bit OS then you need 64 bit java and the same for 32 bit.

Comment: i hava a 64 bit os and 64 bit java.

Answer (score 0):

Check `eclipse.ini` file, and in particular format of the `vm` option (look [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) for more):

> **Note the format of the -vm option - it is important to be exact:**
>
> - The -vm option and its value (the path) must be on separate lines.
> - The value must be the full absolute or relative path to the Java    executable, not just to the Java home directory.
> - The -vm option must occur before the -vmargs option, since everything after -vmargs is    passed directly to the JVM.

Another thing to check is that bit version (32/64) of JVM should match bit version of eclipse (32/64).