# Eclipse JNI failed to load

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi guys i startet eclispe this morning and everything works but a few hours later I get the following message "Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:Windows\system32..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll". I can't find this file. I set JAVA_HOME and the Path component again and nothings works.

Answer (score 0):

Check your pairing of the eclipse and java i.e

```
32-bit OS - 32-bit JDK - 32-bit Eclipse (32-bit only)

64-bit OS - 32-bit JDK - 32-bit Eclipse

64-bit OS - 64-bit JDK - 64bit Eclipse (64-bit only)
```

Check this link [Eclipse reported “Failed to load JNI shared library”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk)

Comment: but it can't not changed the bit version
I only installed The elder scrolls online on my pc since then it can't find the jvm.dll