# How to run Eclipse ADT on Windows8?

Tags: android, windows-8

I would like to install eclipse + ADT on Windows 8. 
The system requirements on [Android Website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) do not list Windows 8 as supported OS. Is it possible to do so?

Also, I see this [Error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/09xwgkdwq1mlo21/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202014-07-09%2023.38.58.png).

Thanks

Comment: First hit on google: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download

Comment: Yes bit this is the requirements:•Windows XP (32-bit), Vista (32- or 64-bit), or Windows 7 (32- or 64-bit)
•Mac OS X 10.5.8 or later (x86 only)
•Linux (tested on Ubuntu Linux, Lucid Lynx) ◦GNU C Library (glibc) 2.7 or later is required.
◦On Ubuntu Linux, version 8.04 or later is required.
◦64-bit distributions must be capable of running 32-bit applications.

Comment: I install this and some java downloads but i get this mensaje: fail to load ...

Comment: I am downloading it now. I have Windows8 as well.

Comment: Perhaps you could change the question to `How to run Eclipse ADT on Windows8?` and describe in the description the steps you have executed and paste the error message.

Comment: I dont upload photo but in the first post I put a link to the img

Comment: The package has been extracted and works well on my Windows8 system. Could you check whether your OS is 32 or 64 bit? Which Eclipse ADT Bit version did you install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean `would you be able to install ADT + eclipse on Windows 8 ??` but according to the system requirements mentioned on [Android Website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) it stops at Windows 7. I do not see a problem however with the installation. It should work. Just make sure you have the correct/updated JVM.

**Operating Systems**

```
Windows XP (32-bit), Vista (32- or 64-bit), or Windows 7 (32- or 64-bit)
Mac OS X 10.5.8 or later (x86 only)
Linux (tested on Ubuntu Linux, Lucid Lynx)
    GNU C Library (glibc) 2.7 or later is required.
    On Ubuntu Linux, version 8.04 or later is required.
    64-bit distributions must be capable of running 32-bit applications.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have Java Problems. I think its related to 32 & 64 bit. See here for a possible duplicate:

[Failed to load the JNI shared Library (JDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk)

Comment: I get it,

1º - I install only the Eclipse, downloading in the official page:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/R/eclipse-standard-luna-R-win32-x86_64.zip

2º - I install the ADT for android developers, this is the instructions

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Next I install de sdk

And run it,

Many thanks for your help,

Regards