# Eclipse IDE included with Android ADT not working

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I have been thinking of starting an Android Development project. I searched on Google for it, it asked me to first install the Android SDK. On visiting http://developer.android.com, I discovered that downloading the SDK only will make it a bit difficult for me to manage the projects, so I downloaded the ADT bundle, which had the **Eclipse IDE** included with it. On testing it, I am finding the SDK to be working properly, but the Eclipse IDE wasn't starting, asking me to install a Java Runtime Environment. Installed that too, copied the jre directory to the eclipse folder, then tried to run eclipse.exe, got an error saying

```
Failed to load the JNI shared library
"C:\Users\Tanmay\Desktop\adt-bundle\eclipse\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll".
```

Please suggest me what shall I do to make the Eclipse IDE work, as working with the SDK through the command line is too tiring..

Comment: First of all welcome to the android world and SO too.Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk?page=1&tab=active#tab-top) to solve your issue.

Comment: Hi, I tried one of the solutions given in that question, that is changing the path of jre in eclipse.ini. Now, It is giving me a different error.
Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/4jtyg4