# I am getting error at the time of starting android eclipse

Tags: android

I have downloaded the android adt-bundle of 64bit, and I am using jdk 1.7.But When I run the application file in eclipse, I am getting this error `Failed to load the JNI shared library`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7385128/1923399

Comment: Yes am using 64bit OS,64bit eclipse,64bit java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It due to mix of 32 and 64 bits 
Kindly cross check that you are using

64-bit OS
64-bit Java
64-bit Eclipse

this is only why, this problem arise.