# How do I force uninstall java updates?

Tags: java

How do I force uninstall java updates.
I tried uninstall from Control Panel and Apps & Features it just won't delete. Tried this [Cannot uninstall Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506119/cannot-uninstall-java) as well it's not working. Any idea ?

Comment: Instead of forcing uninstall, wouldn't it be better to avoid installing of the updates?

Comment: The environment I'm working you, doesn't need updates but IT pushes updates and it's against the policy to block them. I downgrade all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying using java uninstall tool from Oracle,

https://www.java.com/en/download/uninstalltool.jsp