# Error in eclipse installation

Tags: java, eclipse

when I try to install eclipse, it always gives error
**Failed to load JNI shared library**
Please help me with this issue, I have downloaded a new version, but the problem is still exists.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have installed 64-bit Eclipse, you also need a 64-bit Java on your Computer. Try this and open Ecplise again.