# Error: Could not create the java virtual machine issue in eclipse in Windows 7 64bit

Tags: java, eclipse

This is my *eclipse.ini* file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
128M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

This is the error message : 
Error: Could not create the java virtual machine.

[Java was started but returned exit code = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3nY2.png)

Comment: put a `!` symbol before every image tag to show the image on the screen.

Comment: `-vm` must be *before* `-vmargs`. See [documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini): *All lines after `-vmargs` are passed as arguments to the JVM, so all arguments and options for eclipse must be specified before `-vmargs` (just like when you use arguments on the command-line).* Then in section "Specifying the JVM" it says: *The `-vm` option must occur **after** the other Eclipse-specific options (such as `-product`, `--launcher.*`, etc), but **before** the `-vmargs` option, since everything after `-vmargs` is passed directly to the JVM.* Wow, documentation is helpful.

Comment: If you have 64 machine and want to use 64 bit eclipse, make sure the  java that is installed in 64 bit too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini documentation, Place `-vm` before `-vmargs`

```
-vm 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: still it's showing error **Failed** **to** **load** **the** **JNI** **shared** **library** **"C:\Program** **Files** **(x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll**  @uuid

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk

Comment: Got it. Solved. Thank you @uuid