# Unable to Start Talend Tool JAVA Version incompatibility

Tags: java, java-8, talend, jdk1.7

My Talend tool version is 5.6. As mentioned in Talend documentation it needs Java Runtime Environment 7 i.e `jdk1.7`, which is installed - along with set `java_home` in my environment variables. As per me it should work.
However I have `jdk1.8` installed too, but I'm correctly pointing `jdk1.7` path at environment variable.

Alternatively I have tried giving `jdk1.7` path in Talend's `Talend-Studio-win-x86_64.ini` file. It's still giving me error.

Below is snapshot: in `cmd` the installed version shows `jdk1.8` where in `echo %JAVA_HOME%` it shows path of `jdk1.7`

[image]

While starting tool this error comes:

[image]

Comment: Check PATH variable, you most probably have java 8 on the PATH. Change it accordingly.

Comment: i unistalled jre 1.8, and now Talend is running fine. Can i NOT have both jdk 7 and 8 installed in my system, as for some of applications i need jdk 8 too.... how do i configure it??

Comment: You can of course have java 7 and 8 on your system at the same time. There was no need to uninstall jre 1.8 to make Talend work. JDK path in talend ini file should have worked fine, there may be issues with the configuration otherwise.

Comment: Thank you so much Ankit... I think i still haven't rectified entirely. But my Talend tool is now working fine. just one doubt if u could help me with:  What if i have jdk 1.7 already installed in my 64bit System, now if i install jdk1.8 does it upgrade to the previous jdk1.7  or does it create new environment? and how does this jre exactly helps?

Comment: Naga Pradeep's answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39211567/12320424

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a batch file with the following command:
    *Talend-Studio-win-x86_64.exe -vm "[jdk path]\bin"*

Then start the studio by executing this batch.

Comment: I have tried this its giving me a pop up: "Failed to load JNI Shared Library"

Comment: Based on the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352493/failed-to-load-the-jni-shared-library-jdk?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top maybe the platform are not set properly (32 or 64 bits)

Answer (score 1):

Talend is based on eclipse, so you can set the java vm to use in the ini-file. (Sorry, I don't have an installation here right now, I think it is called talend.ini - nevertheless, it is located in talend's installation folder.)

Add the following to the top of the file:

```
-vm
[path to your java 7]/bin/javaw.exe
```

Comment: yes i have tried this too.... by specifying java 7 path in Talend-Studio-win-x86_64.ini file......... at the top of file...but it didnt solved my problem

Comment: The exact syntax is detailed in eclipse documentation : https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini so it must be before vmargs option and there must be a line return between -vm and javaw.exe absolute path

Answer (score 1):

try to make changes in TOS_DI-win-x86_64.ini file

add line

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.14\bin\javaw.exe
```

And update or confirm the version as below.

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11.0.14
```

Hope it'll help to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have talend in c:\talend and jdk1.7 is in C:\jdk1.7. 
You can do like the following in windows environment.

1. Open command prompt.
2. Goto the bin folder location where jdk 1.7 is located. For example if you have jdk in C:\jdk1.7 then 
   cd\

cd C:\jdk1.7\bin

3. Then from bin folder of jdk type the full uri of the executable and hit enter.
   In the above supposition c:\jdk1.7\bin>c:\talend\tos_di-xxxxx.exe

In the above statement tos_di-xxxxx.exe is the executable file depending on the os environment