# Android - Eclipse JRE not found

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I have downloaded Android ADT Bundle and trying to create hello world android app.

I am following [Setting up ADT Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html) which says just extract the zip file and launch the Eclipse.

I am getting following error

"A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: C:\adt\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.exe ..."

I know I can install JRE (with or without JDK), and set up javaw.exe dir in path ENV and the problem will [go away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383587/no-java-virtual-machine-found-starting-eclipse-3-6-1-on-windows-7-64bit-machine).

But I think i ADT bundle should be self sufficient and should not require any additional download. Peculiar thing is that I cannot find jre dir inside eclipse.

Am I missing some additional steps? if yes, what steps?

Comment: Hi @Tilak, I'm new in programming and I don't know much but I had the same problem once and I solved it by installing both `JRE` and `JDK`. I followed instructions mentioned [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java):-D

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this the best way to do but if copy paste the JRE folder inside the ecplise folder it works.

```
But I think i ADT bundle should be self sufficient and should not require any additional download. Peculiar thing is that I cannot find jre dir inside eclipse.
```

I don't think so eclipse folder will be having JRE folder you have to specify the path JDK path in ENV.

Answer (score 1):

Check `Windows -> Preferences -> Compiler` and `Windows -> Preferences -> Installed JREs`.

If not configure them. If you have not installed JDK(It has JRE in it) then install it first.

To verify type `java -version` in your command line.

You should get output like

```
java version "1.7.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_11-b21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)
```

(Java 7 is latest but you can use any version that suits your requirement)

Answer (score 1):

You should Install **JDK** and set class path. Because for compilation you need **JDK**   not just **JRE** and `JDK internally contain JRE`.Therefore no need of installing JRE separately.